# My PrtSc key is not working properly since upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Since upgrading my pc to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I've encountered several issues, but the funniest and most tedious one is definitively this.
When I press the PrtSc key on my keyboard it doesn't take a screenshot.
I checked my computer shortcuts but they are ok (I changed the first one in order to take the following screenshot):
[image]

Using some web application I checked that the key input was ok, and it is.
By change I discovered that pressing the PrtSc key in any text field (I tried the firefox search bar, gedit and vscode) it display a underlined dot [image] and if a write a letter after PrtSc it print the underlined letter [image] that disappears if I write anything else.
After some time spent randomly typing PrtSc and other keys I discovered that it gives shortcuts for non-standard characters:

- PrtSc + s + s = ß
- PrtSc + c + c = č
- PrtSc + x + x = × (I think it's the "times" symbol)
- PrtSc + e + e = ə

Some ideas of what is happening and why, and most important how to fix it, finally giving me back my good old screenshot key?

---

### EDIT 1

The output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` is:

```bash
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search I accidentally found that during the upgrade to 22.04  the PrtSc key was set in the Special Character Entry option, and that was overruling anything else.
Setting again to "Layout default" fixed my problem.

[image]